Using sleuth with opentelemetry with spring based legacy app
We have a few legacy core java based apps written many years ago which frequently interact with each other, couple of years back we migrated the app boot strategy to spring-boot but the codebased has not been mordernized to use spring feature or spring dependency injection. There are many objects that are create with direct use of new operator instead of benefiting from spring DI. Now as part of our observability strategy we are trying to add trace id to our logs. So that we can trace the flow not only just across these systems but within the component as well.
I tried using sleuth with open telementry. I added the dependencies in dependency management section but i do not see the logs getting printed with traceId. Interestingly there are few methods which are annotated with @Async where i can see the traceId perfectly populated upon debugging i see that there is a TraceAsyncAspect with intercepts the @Async boundry and adds the traceId and spanId to MDC context but i do not see traceId being populated on logs printed from methods defined in simple spring bean example below
Now the issue here is how to populate the traceId on logs which are written in classes instantiated outside of spring context.
public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            ApplicationContext cts = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
            cts.getBean(SearchService.class).getLastExecutedSearchTime();
            /// some app code
            notifier.info("Search componet started with last executed time"); --> Log is printed without traceId

        } catch (Exception e) {
            notifier.error(APPLICATION_STARTUP_FAILED_MSG, e);
        }
    }


@Service
public class SearchService implements ISearch {
  @Override
    public String getLastExecutedSearchTime() {
        NOTIFIER.info("Testing log 123"); --> Log is printed without any traceId
        return "sometime";
    }


@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    @Async("threadExecutor")
    void onApplicationReadyEvent() {
        notifier.info("A sample log"); --> Log is printed with tradeId and spanId
    }

}

pom snippets
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.1</version>
        </dependency>

application.properties
spring.application.name=search-app
logging.pattern.level=[%X{traceId}/%X{spanId}] %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n

